# Unable to add space between words while using Angular mat-expansion panel

Tags: angular, angular-material, mat-expansion-panel

I have `text field` in `mat-expansion panel`. I am unable to add `space` when typing a word `Dinbert Syndrome`. When I click on space `down arrow open the panel`

`Below is the image after typed 1st word (Arrow is intact and downwards)`

[image]

`When pressed space, no space is applied but panel opens (arrow upwards)`

[image: When clicked space, panel opens but no space is applied]

**Expected** - `Dinbert Syndrome`

**Text I get** - `DinbertSyndrome`

.html

```
  <mat-expansion-panel-header>
              <mat-panel-title>
                <dt class="col-sm-4 record_property">Product</dt>
              </mat-panel-title>
              <mat-panel-description>
                <dd class="col-sm-8 record_property_value Product_name" id="{{genProductId(product.name)}}">
                  <internal-edit id="concept_{{ci}}_Product_{{ti}}_edit" *ngIf="product.$new" [(field)]="product.name"
                                       [elementType]="rn.productData" (fieldChange)="ProductModified(product)" cols="30" 
                                       rows="1"></internal-edit>
                </dd>
              </mat-panel-description>
            </mat-expansion-panel-header>
```

internalEdit.html

```
<internal-edit [editable]="true"
                   [inputTag]="'textarea'"
                   [(inputText)]="field"
                   (inputTextChange)="termModified(field)"
                   [placeholder]="'Term'"></internal-edit>
```

.ts

```
genProductId(s: string) {
    return s ? s.replace(/ /g, '_') : '';
  }
```

**NOTE**- My selenium-protractor end to end test is failing due to this.

Comment: Would you share the respective code of your e2e test? I believe you can solve your problem there, instead of changing the components code to make the test work.

Comment: Hi @Tino, thanks for reply - here is the link to question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68104526/how-can-i-add-space-between-words-when-typing-in-protractor?noredirect=1#comment120371129_68104526

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68104526/how-can-i-add-space-between-words-when-typing-in-protractor?noredirect=1#comment120398312_68104526